# ARToolkit DSVLD.dll error

Tags: artoolkit

I have followed the tutorial here: http://www.hitl.washington.edu/artoolkit/documentation/devstartup.htm

When I try to compile the program, it will compile but the output window will tell me:

DSVLd.dll(tid 774c) 42818982 : Could not access module key
DSVLd.dll(tid 774c) 42818982 : Could not access GLOBAL module key

And then the program will quit.

I have been able to setup the toolkit according to the instructions and was able to run the sample programs just fine. I am not sure whether or not there is some setup steps I missed or need to configure if I am creating this project from scratch.

I am currently running 64-bit Windows 7.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar debug output when my program is running a linked library using MS directshow (debug version). It seems the debug system is looking for Windows registry keys. But it should not be the reason for a program quitting, at least mine works unaffected.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it just now. Just copy the two files (`data` and `Wrl`) from `ARToolKit\bin\data` and `ARToolKit\bin\Wrl` to the directory `debug` under you own project folder, not just copy to your project folder.